# Adding HoverBehavior to existing kivy code

Tags: python, kivy

I'm very new to Kivy, and even python so I dont have the best of skills. I have a .py file to run everything from my .kv file. I want to add an effect where a widget is highlighted when you hover on it. I found some stuff on github, changed it up to what I want but I cant figure out how to put it in my original and make it work for what I already had. So basically I need help putting the hover stuff into my python file. Its probably an easy answer but again, I'm new to this...

The stuff I need to put into the file...

```
class HoverBehavior(object):
hovered = BooleanProperty(False)
border_point = ObjectProperty(None)

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.register_event_type('on_enter')
    self.register_event_type('on_leave')
    Window.bind(mouse_pos=self.on_mouse_pos)
    super(HoverBehavior, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def on_mouse_pos(self, *args):
    if not self.get_root_window():
        return # do proceed if I'm not displayed <=> If have no parent
    pos = args[1]
    #Next line to_widget allow to compensate for relative layout
    inside = self.collide_point(*self.to_widget(*pos))
    if self.hovered == inside:
        #We have already done what was needed
        return
    self.border_point = pos
    self.hovered = inside

Factory.register('HoverBehavior', HoverBehavior)

class HoverLabel(Label, HoverBehavior):
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        pass

    def on_leave(self, *args):
        pass

    Builder.load_string('''
<HoverLabel>:
    text: "inside" 
    pos: 200,200
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 100, 30
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: 1,0,1 if self.hovered else 0,0,0
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

    ''')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    fl = FloatLayout()
    fl.add_widget(HoverLabel())
    runTouchApp(fl)
```

And my python file:

```
class VgxMainScreen(Widget):
pass


class VgxUI(Widget):
    pass


class CanvasWidget(ButtonBehavior, Label):
    pass


class KivyGuiApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return VgxUI()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    KivyGuiApp().run()
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but behaviors should be listed first in a subclass, i.e., `class HoverLabel(HoverBehavior, Label):`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "somewhat" more organized code of your example (plus some things you missed from the [original code](https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD/blob/master/kivymd/uix/behaviors/hover_behavior.py))

```py
class HoverBehavior(object):
    hovered = BooleanProperty(False)
    border_point = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.register_event_type('on_enter')
        self.register_event_type('on_leave')
        Window.bind(mouse_pos=self.on_mouse_pos)
        super(HoverBehavior, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_mouse_pos(self, *args):
        if not self.get_root_window():
            return # do proceed if I'm not displayed <=> If have no parent
        pos = args[1]
        # Next line to_widget allow to compensate for relative layout
        inside = self.collide_point(*self.to_widget(*pos))
        if self.hovered == inside:
            return # We have already done what was needed
        self.border_point = pos
        self.hovered = inside

        if inside:
            self.dispatch("on_enter")
        else:
            self.dispatch("on_leave")


Factory.register('HoverBehavior', HoverBehavior)

Builder.load_string("""
<VgxMainScreen>:
    HoverLabel:
        text: "1st label" 
        pos: 200,200
    HoverLabel:
        text: "2nd label" 
        pos: 400,200

<HoverLabel>:
    text: "inside"
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 100, 30
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: 1,0,1 if self.hovered else 0,0,0
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
""")


class HoverLabel(HoverBehavior, Label):
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        pass

    def on_leave(self, *args):
        pass


class VgxMainScreen(Widget):
    pass


class KivyGuiApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return VgxMainScreen()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    KivyGuiApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `HoverLabel` code is in a file named `hoverlabel.py` in the same folder as your current python file, you can just add:

```
from hoverlabel import HoverLabel
```

at the top of your python file.